# Setting image to tableview background

Tags: ios, uitableview, background, uiimage, layer

I have added an imageview on top of tableview. I need to set it to the back of tableview without setting it as a background on tableview.

`sendSubviewToBack:bgView` also does not work. Can someone help?

Comment: once read my answer second option it'l helps you.

Comment: have you solved yoyr problem?

Comment: no. I am trying out..but nothing seems to work..

Comment: some where else you went wrong once post your code here.

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
if objects are in xib ,then take imageview infront of tableview in xib,
```

(or)

```
if you are adding in programatically then add imageview before adding the tableview
```

(or)

```
table.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
```

(or)

```
[table bringSubviewToFront:yourImageview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bg_image.png"]];
```

Comment: I can not use any property dealing with background color as my background color is set using a common gradient method.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting what exactly you want . 
One another way from XIB ,  just simply add it into the xib behind your table View , and set your tableView's background colour as clearcolor, So you'll be able to see the image behind your tableview.

Comment: I need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Then just try as Sunny instructed
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];